# How do I set my computer to restart on crash?

Tags: shutdown, restart

I have a computer that occasionally crashes. I am using Teamviewer to access it remotely, but I obviously lose access when it crashes.

Is it possible to switch the default behaviour from shutting down to restarting? Then I could put Teamviewer in my startup programs and solve my post-crash access issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to reboot when there is a kernel panic, you can edit `/etc/default/grub` and add the `panic=10` parameter which will reboot after 10 seconds of a panic. Add it to the line containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, e.g that line should read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash panic=10"
```

You can change that number to the seconds you want to initiate the reboot after the panic. To reboot immediately after a panic add a negative value, e.g. `panic=-1`. After editing that file run `sudo update-grub`.

Alternatively you can edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the

```
kernel.panic = 10
```

line there. It has the same meaning.

Also if you want to reboot on oops-es too, you may add the `oops=panic` kernel parameter in the `/etc/default/grub` file, so the line will read something like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash panic=10 oops=panic"
```

This will trigger a panic on oops-es too and reboot after 10 seconds. (Again don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after editing the grub file.